# Replicating views in Android

Tags: android

I made a view which is a checklist, it has text inputs fields, checkboxes and two buttons, one for save the list and the other for delete all. Ok, but a friend (who is using my app) says "I need this for different kinds of stuff to be listed too". How can I replicate my entire view in an easy way, Should I declare this as a class and then creating several instances?.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the include tag.

For example, if you have your view saved as **file.xml** on your 'layout' folder, you can add it anywhere using this code:

```
<include android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/file" />
```

Comment: Ok Leandroid, nice approach, I will try it and comment here how it was going.